# Run code with certain probability

Tags: c++, c

I'm new to C/C++. I'm trying to make code run with a certain probability.

For example, I know the following code to make it run with 1/2 probability:

```
if (rand() % 2) {
    // runs 1/2 the time
}
```

But I do not know the best way to make it run 1/4 (25%) of the time. When I put in:

```
if (rand() % 4) {
    // runs 1/4 the time
}
```

It runs a lot more than one in four times. I also tried:

```
if (rand() % 2) {
    // 1/2
    if (rand() % 2) {
        // 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4
    }
}
```

Which works, but it doesn't seem like the best way. Also, that method will only work for 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc. I have no idea how to do example like 1/6.

Comment: Do you know how the modulo operator `%` works? Do you know what integer values are evaluated as true and which ones as false?

Comment: Is it C or C++, they are not the same.

Comment: What is difference from C and C++ in my question?

Comment: Someone showed me %. Is used to make it run percent of time, correct?

Comment: `if((rand() % 100)<=25)` runs 25% at a time which is 100/4 if that's what you want?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and clarify how you tested that.

Comment: Note that the code above will not work properly for non-integer divisors of `RAND_MAX + 1` anyway.

Comment: @joecoder No, that is *not* what `%` does. It actually has nothing to do with percentages.

Comment: @Olaf Please stop the cargo-cult pedantry. This is a question that applies to both C and C++. The only case in which it would make a difference is if you were going to write an answer about <random>.

Comment: @Olaf, you're all over this question tearing everyone down, without providing any actual help. Why all the hate? The code is both valid C and C++. And how is his code not minimal, complete, or verifiable?

Comment: @immibis: I'm still looking for that "C/C++" language. About picking C or C++: The title states "Run code with certain probability". `rand` is not the best choice for that, so maybe `C++` provides some better functions and an answer can use that. But if OP uses C only, that would not be allowed.

Comment: @harry: While it is obvious here what the actual problem is, it still is not clear how OP checked the distribution. The error with the inversion (`1/4` vs. `3/4`) is obvious, but how does he check the distribution? Imo that is still relevant. Oh, and I think I very well provide help by asking for clarification. If you provide an answer, you have to be correct and the answer shouild be helpful. Do you actually criticise if you are shown where your answer is wrong or lacks quality?

Answer (score 7):

You should put `== 0` in your `if` statement.

```
if (rand() % 4 == 0) {
    // runs 1/4 the time
}
```

`rand()` returns a positive integer, that may be very large. The modulus operator `%` performs division and gives the remainder. For example, if you take a large number and divide by 4, the remainder must be either 0, 1, 2, or 3. It can't be anything else. By checking that the remainder is equal to 0, we have selected for one of four possible cases. That means a 25 percent probability.

The reason that your original code runs too often, is that `rand() % 4` in your if statement counts everything except 0 as true. So if the remainder is 1, 2, or 3, the condition runs. In other words, your code is running 3/4 of the time.

Comment: DV for not explaining **why**.

Comment: I was in the process of editing to explain why. Not sure why you would down-vote a correct answer.

Comment: 1) To address someone use `@name`. Otherwise your comment is likely not to be noticed! 2) I followed site-rules. An answer without explanation is near to useless, thus "not helpful". So much for the comment. Now the edit: `rand` returns an integer between `0` (which is normally not deemed "positive", but normally neutral with the standard allowing for negative `0` as well). There is a well-defined upper limit and `rand() % 4` might not give a uniform distribution even iff `rand` does. I think OP knows what the modulo-operator does; the problem is more the condition.

Comment: Anyway, I removed the DV, as the explanation is not very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Before we use rand(), we need to set the seed for it. We can use the timestamp e.g. `srand(time(NULL))`.

`rand() % n`'s result has a uniform random distribution in 0, 1, 2... n-1，so just pick a number within them, for example `0`

So if you want to run a code in a certain probability, like `1/6`, you can make `n = 6`, so:

```
n = 6;
if (rand() % n == 0) {
    // your code
}
```

Note: Pay attention to your `n`, it cannot be larger than `RAND_MAX`, which is defined by your compilers.

Comment: `rand` is not guaranteed to provide a good distribution. But it will generate the same sequence if not seeded properly.

Comment: @Olaf : I agree, `rand()` is just a pseudo-random integral generator depends on the seed input. But in a way it can still be applied to some imprecise or non security related algorithms. If we want a totally random sequence, this is another big topic.

Comment: From the question, OP seems to be concerned about the unifirmity - it is just not clear to which degree. Anyway, assuming a haldway acceptable `rand` implementation, the modulo-operator will generate an acceptable distribution only iff(!) the divisor is an integer divisor of `RAND_MAX + 1`. For most implementations, that happens to be true for powers of two. But this also is not guaranteed.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. I still have to get used to my new keyboard. Too late to edit now.

Answer (score -2):

I think everyone here is thinking about this problem the wrong way, there's a much simpler (but a little bit more verbose) way of getting a simple probability such as this, and this way explains itself a little bit better.

```
srand(time(NULL))

int number;

number = rand() % 2 +1;

if (number == 1)
{
     //Do something
}

if (number == 2)
{
     //Do something
}
```

Now, if you're like me and you find that the existing RNG is not random enough, we can tack on what I like to call a method of "Ghetto Gaussian RNG", this will force the computer to generate large numbers, but never use them unless they are equal to 1 or 2.

```
srand(time(NULL))

string sky = "blue"; //string for while loop
int number;
int hold; // hold the initial result of the RNG

while(sky == "blue") //if the sky is blue, keep looping
{

     hold = rand() % 10000 +1;

     number = hold/7; //divide hold by 7, store in number

     if (number == 1)
     {
          //Do something
          break; //if the result of the division above is exactly
                 //1, break the loop
     }

     if (number == 2)
     {
          //Do something
          break; //if the result of the division above is exactly
                 //2, break the loop
     }
}
```

It might look strange, but it really does work for increasing "randomness" in stock RNG's.

Comment: Why `% 10000`? Why the constant `+ 1`? Why divide by 7? None of these things makes it any more "random", it probably screws with the distribution more than it helps. Don't do this.

Comment: 1. So that the program will not attempt to divide by zero.

2. This just increases the randomness, before the program would be searching for the numbers 1 and 2, but now it has to search for the numbers 7 and 14, which are farther apart and have a lower probability to be "drawn" at similar times.

3. No it doesn't screw with the distribution, try it yourself.

Comment: So, I just performed 3 runs of 100000 numbers between 1 and 2 generated in this fashion, divided the sum of all numbers generated by 100000 and got 1.45, 1.50, 1.47, respectively. I really don't know what you're talking about with screwing up the distribution.